# Does Magento loads every xml file from the layout folder?

Tags: magento

When calling $this->loadLayout() in your controller, does Magento fetches **all** of the xml files from the layout folders in the current design package?
I am trying to figure out how the customer login form pulls out the template from:
**persistent/customer/form/login.phtml**, is it because there is only a layout file: **persistent.xml** present?

EDIT:
I figured it out I didn't see there is a new module in 1.6.1.0 and also there are changes in model resource names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer login form pulls in because of the template or code block type referenced in that block's XML tag (in persistent.xml).

Comment: Thank you, though I have figured it out that was a new module added in 1.6.1.0, just couldn't remove the question on time :)